# App builds, but it gets stuck in the installing and running step on Xcode/VS Code (Flutter project)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter

This problem started out of nothing. The app builds perfectly using both VS Code or Xcode, but then when it's in the installing and running step it gets stuck, it doesn't show any errors, it just stuck in this step and my iPhone gets hot.
Info:
My Mac: macOS Monterey - Version 12.2 with M1
iPhone 13 - iOS 15.3
Xcode Version 13.2.1 (13C100)

By the way, the app builds and runs perfectly using a simulator. This problem happens only with my physical iPhone.
I tried reinstalling Xcode but it didn't solve the problem.

The log on Devices and Simulators:
// Log

```
Incident Identifier: 98EC5A4A-D8FD-4314-AA94-A77586E1E476
CrashReporter Key:   3c762f5dc23749edea311baf141fe1da3bd96568
Hardware Model:      iPhone14,5
Process:             cloudd [135]
Path:                /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudKitDaemon.framework/Support/cloudd
Identifier:          cloudd
Version:             ???
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Unspecified
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.apple.cloudd [213]

Date/Time:           2022-02-04 07:35:08.7787 -0300
Launch Time:         2022-02-03 18:31:16.0191 -0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 15.3 (19D50)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    1.41.06
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000001
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000001
VM Region Info: 0x1 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4304289791
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                   1008e4000-1008ec000 [   32K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...upport/cloudd
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [135]

Triggered by Thread:  12

Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b7db1504 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b7db1b9c mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x180667738 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x18066ba2c __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4   CoreFoundation                         0x18067f468 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   Foundation                             0x181e9dc94 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 236
6   Foundation                             0x181e9e450 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 92
7   cloudd                                 0x1008e8154 0x1008e4000 + 16724
8   dyld                                   0x100a35aa4 start + 520

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.CFStream.LegacyThread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b7db1504 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b7db1b9c mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x180667738 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x18066ba2c __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4   CoreFoundation                         0x18067f468 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CoreFoundation                         0x180767b20 _legacyStreamRunLoop_workThread + 300
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a779a4 _pthread_start + 148
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a76ea0 thread_start + 8

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b7db1504 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b7db1b9c mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x180667738 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x18066ba2c __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4   CoreFoundation                         0x18067f468 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CFNetwork                              0x1810f5510 0x180e7b000 + 2598160
6   Foundation                             0x181eed40c __NSThread__start__ + 808
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a779a4 _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a76ea0 thread_start + 8

Thread 3 name:  cloudd.mmcs
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b7db1504 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b7db1b9c mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x180667738 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x18066ba2c __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4   CoreFoundation                         0x18067f468 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CloudKitDaemon                         0x1b48b2328 0x1b46b6000 + 2081576
6   Foundation                             0x181eed40c __NSThread__start__ + 808
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a779a4 _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a76ea0 thread_start + 8

Thread 4 name:  cloudd.mmcs
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b7db1504 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b7db1b9c mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x180667738 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x18066ba2c __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4   CoreFoundation                         0x18067f468 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CloudKitDaemon                         0x1b48b2328 0x1b46b6000 + 2081576
6   Foundation                             0x181eed40c __NSThread__start__ + 808
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a779a4 _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a76ea0 thread_start + 8

Thread 5 name:  cloudd.mmcs
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b7db1504 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b7db1b9c mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x180667738 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x18066ba2c __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4   CoreFoundation                         0x18067f468 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CloudKitDaemon                         0x1b48b2328 0x1b46b6000 + 2081576
6   Foundation                             0x181eed40c __NSThread__start__ + 808
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a779a4 _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a76ea0 thread_start + 8

Thread 6 name:  cloudd.mmcs
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b7db1504 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b7db1b9c mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x180667738 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x18066ba2c __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4   CoreFoundation                         0x18067f468 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CloudKitDaemon                         0x1b48b2328 0x1b46b6000 + 2081576
6   Foundation                             0x181eed40c __NSThread__start__ + 808
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a779a4 _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a76ea0 thread_start + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a76e8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a76e8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.cloudkit.default
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b7db21a4 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libsystem_platform.dylib               0x1f1a6e9a4 _os_unfair_lock_lock_slow + 196
2   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x198f31d94 objc_object::sidetable_clearDeallocating() + 96
3   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x198f34bb4 objc_destructInstance + 144
4   libsystem_blocks.dylib                 0x1f19f37f8 _Block_release + 216
5   libdispatch.dylib                      0x18036b670 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
6   libdispatch.dylib                      0x18036eb44 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 504
7   libdispatch.dylib                      0x18036e1a0 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 596
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x18037cde0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x18037d608 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a770b8 _pthread_wqthread + 228
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a76e94 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a76e8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a76e8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.CloudKit.PCSCache.recordQueue
Thread 12 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x198f35fec objc_loadWeakRetained + 144
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x198f35fc0 objc_loadWeakRetained + 100
2   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x198f39a38 objc_loadWeak + 24
3   Foundation                             0x181ea06e8 -[NSConcreteHashTable countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:] + 144
4   Foundation                             0x181f466f0 -[NSHashTable anyObject] + 68
5   CloudKitDaemon                         0x1b4969b74 0x1b46b6000 + 2833268
6   CloudKitDaemon                         0x1b496a06c 0x1b46b6000 + 2834540
7   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180369924 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x18036b670 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x18037bcfc _dispatch_lane_concurrent_drain + 1000
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1803739d8 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 504
11  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180372ccc _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 376
12  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18037399c _dispatch_lane_invoke + 444
13  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180372ccc _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 376
14  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18037399c _dispatch_lane_invoke + 444
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18037e1b8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 656
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a770f4 _pthread_wqthread + 288
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a76e94 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 13 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.cloudkit.urlrequestlifecycle.0x12836fdb0
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b7db21a4 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libsystem_platform.dylib               0x1f1a6e9a4 _os_unfair_lock_lock_slow + 196
2   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x198f33348 mutex_tt<false>::lockTwo(mutex_tt<false>*, mutex_tt<false>*) + 72
3   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x198f3a3b4 objc_storeWeak + 144
4   Foundation                             0x181f2ae50 -[NSConcreteHashTable rehashAround:] + 236
5   Foundation                             0x181ea223c hashProbe + 524
6   Foundation                             0x181ea5310 -[NSConcreteHashTable addObject:] + 68
7   CloudKitDaemon                         0x1b46d6270 0x1b46b6000 + 131696
8   CloudKitDaemon                         0x1b46fa570 0x1b46b6000 + 279920
9   CloudKitDaemon                         0x1b46c357c 0x1b46b6000 + 54652
10  CloudKitDaemon                         0x1b46de4d0 0x1b46b6000 + 165072
11  CloudKitDaemon                         0x1b4705474 0x1b46b6000 + 324724
12  CloudKitDaemon                         0x1b48805ac 0x1b46b6000 + 1877420
13  CloudKitDaemon                         0x1b474ee6c 0x1b46b6000 + 626284
14  CloudKitDaemon                         0x1b46c7df4 0x1b46b6000 + 73204
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180369924 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
16  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18036b670 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
17  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180372df4 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
18  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18037399c _dispatch_lane_invoke + 444
19  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18037e1b8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 656
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a770f4 _pthread_wqthread + 288
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a76e94 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a76e8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 15 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.CloudKit.PCSCache.callbackQueue.com.apple.backup.ios
Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b7db21a4 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libsystem_platform.dylib               0x1f1a6e9a4 _os_unfair_lock_lock_slow + 196
2   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x198f31d94 objc_object::sidetable_clearDeallocating() + 96
3   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x198f34bb4 objc_destructInstance + 144
4   libsystem_blocks.dylib                 0x1f19f37f8 _Block_release + 216
5   libdispatch.dylib                      0x18036b670 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
6   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180372df4 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
7   libdispatch.dylib                      0x18037399c _dispatch_lane_invoke + 444
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x18037e1b8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 656
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a770f4 _pthread_wqthread + 288
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a76e94 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1a76e8c start_wqthread + 0


Thread 12 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x00000001da67b4c0   x1: 0x0000000000050000   x2: 0x0000000000009203   x3: 0x000000016f976480
    x4: 0x0000000000000010   x5: 0x0000000123ffffe0   x6: 0x0000000000000003   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000000001   x9: 0x0000000000009203  x10: 0x0000000000000001  x11: 0x000000000000001f
   x12: 0x0000000000419900  x13: 0x03729501da689661  x14: 0x0000000100aca830  x15: 0x00000001da689660
   x16: 0x00000001f1a70670  x17: 0x0000000181ea0658  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000001
   x20: 0x00000001da67b3c0  x21: 0x000000012482d908  x22: 0x00000001da687000  x23: 0x000000016f9770e0
   x24: 0x00000001da67b3c0  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000123e88060  x27: 0x0000000100d04ac0
   x28: 0x0000000100d01dc0   fp: 0x000000016f976430   lr: 0xd508a90198f35fc0
    sp: 0x000000016f976400   pc: 0x0000000198f35fec cpsr: 0x60001000
   far: 0x0000000000000001  esr: 0x92000006 (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault

Binary Images:
       0x1b7db0000 -        0x1b7de3fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <ff3ee512a0bc3123b983d365a71fb06a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x180660000 -        0x180ab3fff CoreFoundation arm64e  <32058d875c5d3117bf4cd547ec3aa6ff> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
       0x181e85000 -        0x18218bfff Foundation arm64e  <4c19d59f844336a28c61161b38f909c9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
       0x1008e4000 -        0x1008ebfff cloudd arm64e  <95a3ae31e9c0312f8df8960d0e359033> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudKitDaemon.framework/Support/cloudd
       0x100a1c000 -        0x100a73fff dyld arm64e  <780553c7d39f322a8cb9f4f6de52610d> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x1f1a76000 -        0x1f1a81fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <a17d07cfe86a392387c4921045898a8a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x180e7b000 -        0x18133ffff CFNetwork arm64e  <23a465f1e97c36c5a30fcefec059f79f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
       0x1b46b6000 -        0x1b4aa6fff CloudKitDaemon arm64e  <dcb4be102e7d31ddb5fe148b47105aa5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudKitDaemon.framework/CloudKitDaemon
       0x1f1a6e000 -        0x1f1a74fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64e  <9472a9a590073c6d849eec1a6890dbd1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
       0x198f30000 -        0x198f69fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64e  <56a134b6c3d83d91b1fc7bdb75c5903b> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
       0x1f19f2000 -        0x1f19f3fff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64e  <36604a97604e3efe9197e0f48f33ee59> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
       0x180367000 -        0x1803adfff libdispatch.dylib arm64e  <bd02a62584753fd68dc38aed25d1573b> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? unknown-arch  <00000000000000000000000000000000> ???

EOF
```

Comment: Did you get any error logs ? and are you running from xcode or using vscode for origional device ?

Comment: I tried running from Xcode and VS code and the same thing happens. On Xcode when I stop it, and go on Window > Devices and Simulators to check the phone, it says it's busy. But during the process the phone connection is normal. On Devices and Simulators where is "crash" log. I will attach to the problem.

Comment: @HardikMehta I added the log

Comment: Can you please provide your pubspec file with your main function? This error can happen because you add something new from pub.dev and it may require some tweaking. Example: MLKit require additional Firebase code in order to work on real device.

Comment: @CidQu I can, but this is happening even with a brand new project, and this same project works with a real iPhone device with my coworkers. I just don't have another iPhone to test if it could be a problem with my iPhone. But do you still think it might be the problem?